# authentication before creation of database item

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, service-reference

Hi i have this problem with some authentication and creation of database item.
In the documentation it says that authentication should be called before the creation. So here is the code i have done and i wonder if i have the events in wrong order.

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_5(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gateway.AuthenticateAsync("username", "password1", "username2", "password2");
        Gateway.AuthenticateCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.AuthenticateCompletedEventArgs>(AuthenticateTime);    
    }

    private DateTime _nestedDateStart;
    private DateTime _nestedDateEnd;
    private DateTime _nestedDateStartBreak1;
    private DateTime _nestedDateEndBreak1;
    private DateTime _nestedDateStartBreak2;
    private DateTime _nestedDateEndBreak2;

    ServiceReference.TimereportDto Timereport = new ServiceReference.TimereportDto();

    void AuthenticateTime(object sender, ServiceReference.AuthenticateCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        Gateway.AuthenticateAsync("username1", "password1", "username2", "password2");     

        Timereport.Started = _nestedDateStart;
        Timereport.Ended = _nestedDateEnd;

        Timereport.Break1Start = _nestedDateStartBreak1;
        Timereport.Break1End = _nestedDateEndBreak1;

        Timereport.Break2Start = _nestedDateStartBreak2;
        Timereport.Break2End = _nestedDateEndBreak2;

        Timereport.Comment = Notes.Text;
        Timereport.EmployeeSignature = "apptest";

        Gateway.CreateTimereportAsync(Timereport,"ABD");
        Gateway.CreateTimereportCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.CreateTimereportCompletedEventArgs>(CreateTimereportCompleted);

    }

    void CreateTimereportCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.CreateTimereportCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

When i set a Breakpoint on "CreateTimereportCompleted" i get error as shown below in the image:

[image]

As you can see it returns message "Access denied,please login first". So becaus the usernames and passwords are correct i figure that i must have the code in wrong order or something.

**UPDATE**

Gateway is a servicereference that looks like this:

```
ServiceReference.GatewaySoapClient Gateway = new ServiceReference.GatewaySoapClient();
```

And if the Authentication cookie is supposed to be passed to the next service call i dont know. Nothing is saying that in the documentation.

They have in the documentation below the Authentication a CookieContainer but isnt that only when you make it for a webbrowser?

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Can you please expand the question to include.. what is GateWay Object and does it has something to do with Authentication cookie being passed on to the next service call?

Comment: Have updated my question, hope its giving more sense to the mess

Comment: GatewayAuthenticateAsync is your WCF call and is it linked with WCF default Authentication Service or your own implementation? Or try calling this Authenticate inside your wcf code for CreateTimereportAsync and see once the call has been successful try to get the data from database.. ( Call to Authenticate happening before Database retrieval inside WCF CreateTimereport method just for checking to see if it runs that way

Comment: Its my own implementation. As you can see i have tried to call Authenticate inside my CreateTimereportAsync. Or really i have just added the gateway.authenticationasync to the "AuthenticateTime" void and there is where i am as you can see. How should i try to use the authenticateasync do you mean?

Comment: i meant inside the wcf method.. and not in your windows phone method right..(you may have to pass username and passwords to wcf function).  I am just trying to move the focus inside wcf to check if this really has something to do with authentication token being passed around

Comment: Its a Service Reference. Do you want me to check the code in there am i understanding you right? I can give you the URL and you can add it to a project to easier see.

Comment: I meant like this Gateway.CreateTimereportAsync(Timereport,"ABD",user1,pass1,user2,pass2); and inside CreateTimerReport in WCF call the Gateway.Authenticate and try to acces the database. A url with access codes(user/pass) always helps, but I dont know how better I can help you with that reference though..

Comment: Here is all the operations for the service: 
http://www.transpalive.se/transpawebserviceslive/gateway.asmx
The CreateTimereportAsync only takes three aurguments.

Comment: and sample user1/pass1 user2/pass2?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30326/discussion-between-alexander-mogren-and-rohith-nair)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Method 1:-  (Without forcefully passing cookies through code)***

In your ASMX web config
add aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" and set AllowCookies=false

In your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig  add AllowCookieContainer=true

**Method 2:- (Passing cookies around via code)**

In your ASMX web config set AllowCookies=true
In your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig  add AllowCookieContainer=true
and you can set

client.CookieContainer=yourCookieContainerVariable

and pass along this 'yourCookieContainerVariable' to next service call.

This method is particularly useful when you have a separate url for your authenticationa nd other business functions

As depicted in : http://www.kotancode.com/2010/08/06/aspnet-authentication-wp7/